# Firedac - Changing SQL statement to return a different result set via cte

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac

My problem is at runtime (Delphi10 vcl)  my fdquery will only return the structure that I use in the first run. Tried release, open, close, empty view, etc... Question: What is needed to clear the columns and structure from my initial run of the fdquery component so the same instance can return different data sets in subsequent runs?  (See section - THIS IS MY Question below)

```
    declare @ctes varchar(max),
        @sql1 varchar(max),
        @sql2 varchar(max),
        @sql3 varchar(max),
        @sqltemp1 varchar(max),
        @sqltemp2 varchar(max),
    @dbyr varchar(25),
    @dbyrstu varchar(25),
    @dbyrads varchar(25),
    @dbyrdsp varchar(25),
        @yr1  int,
        @Startyr  int,
        @yr2  int,
        @Endyr int,
    @x int

-- KETools (uncomment)
set @startyr = :parmStartYear
set @Endyr   = :parmEndYear
set @x       = :parmX

-- SQL uncomment to test)
-- set @startyr = 2017
-- set @Endyr   = 2016
-- set @x = 4

set @yr1 = @startyr
set @yr2 = @Endyr

set @dbyrstu = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..stu'
set @dbyrads = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..ads'
set @dbyrdsp = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..dsp'


while @yr1 >= @yr2 
begin
     set @ctes = '
        with cteSusData
        as  (
            select  s.id,s.sc, l.nm [School - '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+'] , s.ln+'', ''+s.fn [Student Name]
            , isnull(case
               when s.ec = 500 then ''Hispanic''
               when s.ec = 600 then (select DE from cod where tc = ''STU'' and FC = ''RC1'' and cd = s.rc1)
              end,'''') Ethnicity
            , isnull(case
                when s.sp = ''S'' then ''SDC''
                when s.u6 = ''R'' then ''RSP''
                when s.u6 = ''D'' then ''DIS''
                when (c.ed is not null and (c.xd is null or c.xd = '''')) Then ''SDC*''
              end,''REG'') EdTYPE
            , s.de [Days Enrolled]
            , s.dp [Days Present]
            , s.da [Days Absent]
            , d.dy [number of Days suspended]
            , d.ds [TYPE]
            , convert(varchar(10), d.dd,101) [Date Suspended]
            ,case
               when month(d.dd) between 8 and 12 then year(d.dd)
               when month(d.dd) between 1 and 7 then year(d.dd)-1
             end [SchoolYear]

            from '+@dbyrstu+' s inner join '+@dbyrads+' a
            on s.id = a.pid and s.sc = a.scl
            inner join '+@dbyrdsp+' d 
            on a.pid = d.pid and a.sq = d.sq 
            inner join loc l
            on s.sc = l.cd
            left join cse c
            on s.id = c.id
            where s.sc between 29 and 72
            and d.ds like ''%SUS%''
            )
        , cteSummarySusDateEthnicity
        as (
           select distinct sc,[School - '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+'] ,Ethnicity
           ,count(*) over (partition by sc,ethnicity) [Ethnicity Suspensions]
           ,EdTYPE
           ,count(*) over (partition by sc,ethnicity,EdTYPE) [EdType Suspensions]
           ,count(*) over (partition by sc) [Total School Suspensions]
           from cteSusData
           where SchoolYear = '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+'
           )
        , cteSummarySusSchool
        as (
           select distinct sc
                 ,[School - '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+'] 
                 ,sum([Ethnicity Suspensions])over (partition by sc) [Total Suspension - '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+']
                 from cteSummarySusDateEthnicity
           )'
    --------- Full run
    set @sql1 = @ctes + ' select * from cteSusData'
                      + ' where  SchoolYear = '+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+'' 
                      + ' order by cteSusData.sc,cteSusData.[Student Name] '  --,cteSusData.[School of Suspension]
    --------- Summary by ethnicity
    set @sql2 = @ctes + ' select  * from cteSummarySusDateEthnicity '
    --------- Summary by School
    set @sql3 = @ctes + ' select * from cteSummarySusSchool '

    --------- Make temp files for final combine 
    set @sqltemp1 = replace(@sql3,'select * from cteSummarySusSchool','select * into amc..tempke'+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))+' from cteSummarySusSchool')

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----  This is my question ???? If I set the parmeter X in my calling code how do you clear the FDquery so the next call returns the next dataset
----  Works fine at design time but not runtime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if @x = 1  execute (@sql1) -- Full run
    if @x = 2  execute (@sql2) -- Summary by ethnicity
    if @x = 3  execute (@sql3) -- Summary by School
    if @x = 4  execute (@sqltemp1) -- Make temp files for combing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    set @yr1 = @yr1-1
    set @dbyrstu = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..stu'
    set @dbyrads = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..ads'
    set @dbyrdsp = 'DST'+cast(@yr1-2000 as varchar(5))+'000CUSD..dsp'

end

if @x = 4 and @startyr = 2017 and @Endyr = 2016
begin
    select a.*,b.[Total Suspension - 2016]
    ,cast(cast((cast(a.[Total Suspension - 2017]as real)/cast(b.[Total Suspension - 2016] as real))*100 as decimal(10,0)) as varchar (25))+' %' [Change (2017/2016)*100]
    --,cast(cast(((cast(-a.[Total Suspension - 2017]as real)+cast(b.[Total Suspension - 2016] as real))*100/(cast(a.[Total Suspension - 2017] as real))) as decimal(10,0))  as varchar (25))+'%' [% Change]
    from amc..tempke2017 a left join amc..tempke2016 b
    on a.sc = b.sc
end


-- Remove temp tables - see @x = 4 above
set @yr1 = @startyr
while @yr1 >= @yr2 and @x = 4 and @startyr = 2017 and @Endyr = 2016
begin
     set @sqltemp2 = 'drop table amc..tempke'+cast(@yr1 as varchar(5))
     execute (@sqltemp2) 
     -- print @sqltemp2
     Set @yr1 = @yr1-1
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong, but I cannot imagine what this story is about. One sidenote, if you want to move data from one DBMS to another, use `TFDBatchMove`. Changing SQL command whilst moving data I would not recommend. FireDAC query object cannot describe a _different_ dataset as long as a different command is prepared (or in other words, you prepare a command, FireDAC describes dataset fields).

Comment: All the background about CTE and building your query are utterly irrelevant. You would experience the same problem if you tried two simple select queries in the same component. So, you give a text wall of irrelevant ...... and not a single line of code! _Learn to create a [mcve], it will vastly increase your odds of getting help._

Comment: Question edited to include short code sample. I talk a lot with non programmers so excuse the narrative. Will make multiple components if stack has no answer or consolidation of code in this manor is not possible. Thank you

Comment: Resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @OneFiveOne Clearly you use a vastly different definition of "short" to the one commonly accepted. I have no qualms with including _appropriate_ narrative, but let me point out that: if you "talk a lot with non programmers" about CTEs, you're likely to get glazed-over eyes. TIP: Practice the skill of staying on topic. It works with both programmers and non-programmers alike. ;)

Comment: You have been very clear about how to ask a question. Do you have an answer? Thanks but the issue is resolved. You should block yourself.